# Maximum extension in spring

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, spring, equilibrium

Suppose a mass $m$ is attached to a spring. Now if the mass is released, the tension will be the restoring force of the spring and since the mass is neither going up nor going down, we have $kx=mg$ or $x=\frac{mg}{k}$.

Now we approach it from another direction. The initial energy of the system is $0$ and the present energy of the system is $\frac{1}{2}kx^2+mg(-x)$. Here in this case $x=\frac{2mg}{k}$. Where did we go wrong then? Since the both aren't equal.

Comment: If you release the mass it starts accelerating downwards so when it reaches the point where $kx=mg$ it has a non-zero velocity $v$ and hence a KE $\tfrac12mv^2$. This is different from having the mass stationary at the distance where $kx=mg$.

Comment: I saw somewhere that the first case is applicable when we move the mass slowly and the second case,when the mass drops suddenly?What difference does moving slowly make?Or moving fast makes?

Comment: Regarding you response to John Rennie, you need to edit your question to indicate the mass is slowly lowered and then released.

Comment: @madness the difference is that when you slowly (adiabatically) release the mass, you are doing work! How much work? Well, exactly equal to the missing kinetic energy.

Answer (score 0):

> Now if the mass is released, the tension will be the restoring force of the spring and since the mass is neither going up nor going down

But at that point the velocity (kinetic energy) is non-zero. So the claim that it neither goes up or down is false.

In your energy conservation statement, you have zero kinetic energy and that happens only at maximum displacement which is at $x=2mg/k$ (and $0$). And if you plug this in (basically $2x$ you’ll see that there’s no problem.

Comment: But maximum compression means that the mass is still there,shouldn't the forces then be equal?

Comment: @madness I’m sorry I did not get you. Can you rephrase?

Answer (score 0):

If the mass is released it will also have kinetic energy. You must include the kinetic energy in your expression.

Answer (score 0):

If your mass is attached to the bottom of an un-stretched vertically hanging spring and released, the spring is initially exerting no force, and the mass will accelerate downward due to gravity.  If you choose the zero point for gravitational energy at the equilibrium position where mg – kx = 0, it will start with gravitational energy mgx, and pass equilibrium with kinetic energy (1/2)m$v^2$ and  spring energy (1/2)k$x^2$.